# How to detect iPhone orientation while only supporting portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift

I want an app to maintain the same UI despite of what the device orientation is. I don't want the default behavior when supporting multiple device orientations where the UI slides / shifts automatically each time the orientation changes. However, I also want to detect what the orientation is in order to perform some custom code.

- UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification doesn't seem to get sent when supportedDeviceOrientations in Info.plist is set to only portrait.
- Overriding supportedInterfaceOrientations didn't seem to do anything.

Is there a way to get information on the device's orientation (it WOULD have been in landscape right now) while only allowing for one device orientation in Info.plist?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is update your Info.plist to support all orientations.

Then in your root view controller you override `supportedInterfaceOrientations`:

```swift
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

This keeps your view controller in portrait regardless of the device orientation but it also allows device orientation change notifications to still be sent as the device orientation changes.

This assumes that rotation lock is not enabled on the iPhone. If the user locks the rotation then an app can't get device orientation change notifications at all. But that's basically the point of the rotation lock.

Comment: How could you get the device orientation when the user locks rotation, then? In my camera app, the user might have their phone orientation locked but they still want the photos which they take horizontally to appear horizontally.

Comment: @Plato I don't know. I do what I described in one of my apps and when rotation lock is off, everything works just fine. But when rotation lock is on, I don't get device rotation notifications. But I know the stock Camera app works whether rotation lock is on or off. So either there is a way with public APIs or Apple is cheating.

Comment: FYI: @HangarRash - I just tested camera app on iOS 17.2. In this iOS version, I don't see what you mention re Camera app. On my iPhone it acts like it only supports Portrait (regardless of rotation lock setting). On my iPad it respects the lock. If lock while home screen is Landscape, Camera app stays Landscape. Similarly for Portrait staying Portrait. Perhaps Apple has fixed some bug re locking.

Comment: @Plato: AFAIK, that is intended to be impossible. By design, rotation lock means physical orientation of device is ignored.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Turn on rotation lock on the iPhone. Run the Camera app. Turn the device to landscape and you will see a couple of the icons rotate 90º. It occurs to me that the Camera app could be using CoreMotion to detect the orientation even when locked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you take in place @hangarrash answer, to detect iPhone orientation you can use NotificationCenter and some combine publisher.

```
import Combine
...
private let cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
...
NotificationCenter
            .default
            .publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                
                let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
                switch orientation {
                case .unknown:
                    ...
                case .portrait:
                    ...
                case .portraitUpsideDown:
                    ...
                case .landscapeLeft:
                    ...
                case .landscapeRight:
                    ...
                case .faceUp:
                    ...
                case .faceDown:
                    ...
                @unknown default: break
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
```